# MongoDB using Spark Java

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark

When I run the code I'm getting the output as shown , how to fix this? thanks
Here I have used spark java
Mongodb 
Intellij Idea
Should get Spark, Java, and MongoDB to work together

package com.mongodb;

```
import spark.Request;
import spark.Response;
import spark.Route;
import spark.Spark;

/**
 * Created by td on 10/20/2016.
 */
public class HelloWorldSparkStyle {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Spark.get("/" ,new Route() {
            public Object handle(Request request, Response response) throws Exception {
                return "Hellow World from Spark";
            }
        });
    }
}

[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @1089ms
[Thread-0] INFO spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer - == Spark has ignited ...
[Thread-0] INFO spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer - >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567
[Thread-0] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.3.6.v20151106
[Thread-0] ERROR spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer - ignite failed
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer.ignite(EmbeddedJettyServer.java:128)
    at spark.Service.lambda$init$0(Service.java:349)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Process finished with exit code 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

means that the port you start your web server on (**4567**) is already used by another process. Kill this process or use another port (ex: **8090** etc).

Comment: when I run this

Comment: when i run this command in cmd                                                              taskkill /pid 4567 /f    it gives the processs not found

Comment: `PID` is process id, and I am talking about `port` `4567`. Run `netstat -ano|findstr 4567`. If it prints something then run taskkill /pid <last column of previous output>.

Comment: C:\>netstat -ano|findstr 4567
  TCP    0.0.0.0:4567           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       19060
  TCP    [::]:4567                   [::]:0                    LISTENING       19060

Comment: Now run: `taskkill /pid 19060` and after that rerun your spark application. It should work.

Comment: Soo... If it helped and your application starts, could you accept the answer?

Comment: I mean, mark answer as correct: by clicking on green check at the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

it means there is a process running on port 4567. Try to run on other port

```
Spark.port(9999);
Spark.get("/" ,new Route() {
public Object handle(Request request, Response response) throws Exception {
    return "Hellow World from Spark";
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

go to command prompt/ terminal (in case of mac).

> ps aux | grep spark

It will give the list of process running by spark. 
Kill the process and restart the application again.